# R Return max count in vector

Tags: r

How would you return the number that repeats the most in a number vector?

For example I would like to return 1 in

```
x <- c(1,1,2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> t <- table(x)
> names(t)[which.max(t)]
[1] "1"
```

This returns the first value with the most entries.  To return them all:

```
> names(t)[t == max(t)]
[1] "1"
```

This is the same for your data.  Here the two expressions would differ:

```
> x <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6)
> t <- table(x)
> names(t)[t == max(t)]
[1] "1" "4" "6"
```